# Missing translation in German StackOverflow careers

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, localization

Go to [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/) and select German at the bottom of the page.

Scroll to around the middle of the page and you will find the English words Featured Jobs as a heading.

[image: Featured Jobs]

Note that French StackOverflow Careers does not have this bug as it does have those words translated.

Comment: What about the word "Keywords"? Ir is that the correct translation?

Comment: please could you check over the translations below for me - I barely speak German. It may be that not all of them need changing - the German may be the same as the English.

Comment: `Entdecken Sie Featured Companys und Entwickler-Positionen in diesen Hightech-Zentren weltweit.` 
would IMHO read better as:  
`Entdecken Sie empfohlene Firmen/Unternehmen und Entwicklerpositionen in diesen Hightechzentren weltweit.`

Comment: `Präsentieren Sie sich als Featured Company ....`  could be worded as `Präsentieren Sie sich als empfohlenes/vorgestelltes Unternehmen
 
Wenn Ihr Unternehmen seinen Sitz in einer dieser Städte hat, können Sie eine kostenlose Firmenseite/Unternehmensseite erstellen, die zu unserem Verzeichnis hinzugefügt wird.`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The term "Featured jobs" is purposely not translated.

The reason is that there is no literal translation for it in German. Keeping the terms in English is more understandable than using an approximate/bad translation.

Thanks for your report!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no German expert, and any translations are Google's work. Please correct them if they are wrong.

The footer doesn't seem to have translated:

[image]

"Info", "FAQ", "Support" and "Blog" all look like English words to me...

"Info" seems to be fine (although I don't know if "info" is a valid abbreviation of "Informationen".

Google thought that "häufig gestellte Fragen" was the translation of "Frequently Asked Questions", so maybe that should be "HGF"? *FAQ seems to be a valid translation into German, so either or I guess*.

"Unterstützung" is the German translation of support I believe.

"Blog" seems to be fine - I expect that has been adopted into most languages.

On the Städte tab (Cities), "Explore Cities <sup>beta</sup>" is in English - maybe "Entdecken Sie Städte <sup>beta</sup>" is better?

Comment: FAQ could well be something that just translates as-is in German: http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-german/faq

Comment: @Robert Updated it

Comment: I would not translate Info, FAQ, Support and Blog they are common knowledge in German for people with some computer knowledge. While HGF is correct it's quite unusual.

Comment: @bummi not even translate Support? I mean, I recognise the word Städte, but if I translate a German page, I'd want that translated for me...

Comment: Support is IMHO very common in german for if you want to translate it I'd prefer Hilfe over Unterstützung, but it's just an opinion. Maybe german.stackexchange.com would be useful to find the best translation.

Comment: Okay - I don't mind, I'm just thinking about what I'd want to see on a translation :)